# Is using nohup with shell (or command) module in ansible idempotent?

Tags: ansible, nohup, idempotent

I'm writing an ansible task which is similar to the following,

```
- name: Start daemon
  shell: nohup myexeprogram arg1 arg2 &
```

(ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29818158/198660)

Is the above task idempotent? i.e. will running it repeatedly end up creating multiple instances of `myexeprogram` on the system or will only one be created?

If the former (i.e. a new instance is created for every task run), is it possible to write a play using this task to be idempotent? Perhaps to run some kind of search & kill command for any existing instances before starting a new one? Examples (ansible tasks) will be appreciated.

**Background:** I'm trying to setup a prometheus server with ansible on a centos7 system.

Comment: You will be much better off writing a unit file for the prometheus service and use the service module with Ansible.

Comment: @knowhy ansible's service module is primarily built around systemv, which prometheus supports, but centos7 has moved away from that into systemd, so using the service module isn't an option for me.

Comment: I have not looked into the code. I never had problems with service module and systemd. I only needed command module for `daemon-reload` once to activate the unit file. Systemd is supported by the module.

Answer (score 2):

No this task will not be idempotent. It will spawn a new instance on every run.

You could make it idempotent by using another task to check for an existing running process and using a 'when' conditional on this task to avoid running if a process is already running.

That said daemonizing the program and using the 'service' module is a better pattern than using command and nohup.